# Display entire error message from logfile using powershell

Tags: powershell

One of the batch scripts creates a logfile and it can have error messages like as below

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'ABC', Procedure 'proc_test1', Line 189:
There is already an object named 'table_test' in the database.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 4:
Server 'ABC', Procedure 'proc_test2', Line 197:
Invalid column name 'employee'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 4:
Server 'ABC', Procedure 'proc_test2', Line 197:
Invalid column name 'address'.
```

Using a powershell script to read and report errors to a mail from the log file. And i'm using this, which excludes certain warning messages too.

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\Users\BatchLog_20200911.txt' -Pattern "Msg","Error" | Select-String -Pattern "SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0" -notmatch | select-object -Property Line,LineNumber
```

Output is as below

```
Line                                                                                                                LineNumber
----                                                                                                                ----------
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1:                                                                                              2791
Msg 207, Level 16, State 4:                                                                                               2794
Msg 207, Level 16, State 4:                                                                                               2797
CT-LIBRARY error:                                                                                                         2828
    ct_results(): network packet layer: internal net library error: Net-Library operation terminated due to disconnect       2829
"Errors encountered during execution.  Exited with status: 596"                                                           4168
```

So, it just prints line which match the query. I want to print the next lines which has actual error message description. Any advise here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-Context` parameter of the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet:

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\Users\BatchLog_20200911.txt' "Msg","Error" -Context 0,1 | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_.Context.PostContext[0] -notmatch 'SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0') {
      [pscustomobject] @{
        Line = $_.Context.PostContext[0]
        LineNumber = $_.LineNumber
      }
    }
  }
```

- `-Context 0,1` captures `0` lines *before* and `1` line *after* along with the actually matching line.
- In the resulting [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instance, `.Context.PostContext[0]` provides access to the first post-context (after) line.

With your sample input, the above yields:

```
Line                                            LineNumber
----                                            ----------
Server 'ABC', Procedure 'proc_test1', Line 189:          1
Server 'ABC', Procedure 'proc_test2', Line 197:          4
Server 'ABC', Procedure 'proc_test2', Line 197:          7
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @mklement0

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @Kris.